# Cut linestring segment at centroid in PostGIS

Tags: postgis, sql, linestring, snapping, centroids

In a table of linestring three segments are connected.

*first--second--third*

could Postgis generate the centroid of second segment and merge first and third at center?
Is it possible?

*first--centroid--third*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The centroid of a line is not always on the line. What you want is the center along the line, you should look at the [ST_LineInterpolatePoint](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_LineInterpolatePoint.html), with a 0.5 parameter you can get the center of the second, if it's what you want.

I'm guessing you want the global center. You should before merge the lines with [ST_LineMerge](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_LineMerge.html). Then you can split the line with this center with [ST_Split](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Split.html).

Comment: Great! Work Fine. That's what I expected. Thank's!